# Is Chebyshev inequality $P[|X-\mu|\ge a] \le \frac{Var(X)}{a^2}$ valid with > instead of $\ge$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Assume $X_{1}, X_{2}, X_{3},...$ are independent and identically distributed exponential random variables with mean of $2$. Using Chebyshev's inequality, how large is n so that $P[|\bar X_n -2|\le 0.001] \ge .95$?

Chebyshev is $P[|X-\mu|\ge a] \le \frac{Var(X)}{a^2}$

Since the given inequality has signs that are opposite of Chebyshev, I rewrite the given as: 
$P[|\bar X_n -2|\le 0.001] = 1- P[|\bar X_n -2|> 0.001]$

So $1- P[|\bar X_n -2|> 0.001] \ge .95$

So $.05 \ge P[|\bar X_n -2|> 0.001]$

So $P[|\bar X_n -2|> 0.001] \le .05$ Is this rearrangement of chebyshev inequality valid?

Since $\mu = 2, \lambda = .5$ and 
we find that $Var(X) = 4$
Note $a = .001, Var(\bar X_n)=\frac{4}{n}$

Comment: For the title: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#Sharpness_of_bounds For your actual question (which I think is rather poorly titled): yes, it's the same, because $\overline{X}_n$ is a continuous random variable so it attains any given value with probability zero.